# What is the right way to send JSON to clients?

Tags: javascript, json, pebble-watch

I want to develop an app for Pebble. This app is going to tell you how long it takes from one place you set in options to another one taking in account traffic jams and stuff.
To achieve this I need to make a page that will return JSON. Pebble retrieves information using code like that:

```
var cityName = 'London';
var URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + cityName;

ajax(
 {
  url: URL,
  type: 'json'
},
function(data) {
  // Success!
  console.log('Successfully fetched weather data!');
},
function(error) {
  // Failure!
  console.log('Failed fetching weather data: ' + error);
}
);
```

I created a small page with a js script that gets needed information from Yandex API:

```
    var route;
      ymaps.ready(init);
var myMap;

function init(){    


  function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
  }   

        var time = 0;
        var home = getParameterByName("h");
        var work = getParameterByName("w");
      ymaps.route([home, work],{avoidTrafficJams: true}).then(
            function (router) {
                route=router;
                time = ((route.getTime())/60).toFixed(2);

               var info = new Object;
                info["home"] = home;
                info["work"] = work;
                info["time"] = ~~time+"m"+~~((time%1)*60)+"s";
                JSON.stringify(info);
            },
            function (error) {
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + error.message);
            }
            );    
}
```

As you can see I can get a JSON string in the end. But how do I send it to clients when a request with right parameters is made?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using phantomjs and executing this js script on my php page.